# how to send whole xml file with data in azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

If I am trying to send xml file it is giving 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' exception.Is there any other way to send xml file name with data in azure service bus.

```
 foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\shubham.mittal\Desktop\xml", "*.xml"))
            {
                string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(contents);

                BrokeredMessage b = new BrokeredMessage(doc);
                //Send the message to the queue.
                client.Send(b);
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just skip `XDocument` parsing step, you don't need it:

```cs
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
BrokeredMessage b = new BrokeredMessage(contents);
```